# Opening txt file in record format in R

Tags: r

I'm looking to read a txt file in record format in R as a dataframe with each row corresponding to a single record. Records are of varying lengths. Any idea how I do this?

This is the first record:

```
# C. elegans orthologs      
# WormBase version: WS241       
# Generated:        
# File is in record format with records separated by "=\n"      
#      Sample Record        
#      WBGeneID \t PublicName \n        
#      Species \t Ortholog \t MethodsUsedToAssignOrtholog \n        
# BEGIN CONTENTS        
=       
WBGene00000001  aap-1   
Ascaris suum    GS_11030    WormBase-Compara
Brugia malayi   WBGene00227541  WormBase-Compara
Bursephelenchus xylophilus  BUX.s00055.227  WormBase-Compara
Caenorhabditis angaria  Cang_2012_03_13_00205.g6964.t3  WormBase-Compara
Caenorhabditis brenneri WBGene00194098  TreeFam; WormBase-Compara
Caenorhabditis briggsae WBGene00032086  Hillier-set; OrthoMCL; Inparanoid_7; OMA;     WormBase-Compara
Caenorhabditis japonica WBGene00207613  WormBase-Compara
Caenorhabditis remanei  WBGene00069407  Inparanoid_7; OMA; TreeFam; WormBase-Compara
Caenorhabditis sp.11    Csp11.Scaffold542.g3421.t1  WormBase-Compara
Caenorhabditis sp.5 Csp5_scaffold_00676.g14307.t1   WormBase-Compara
Danio rerio ENSEMBL:ENSDARP00000056212  TreeFam
Dirofilaria immitis nDi.2.2.2.t01810    WormBase-Compara
Drosophila melanogaster ENSEMBL:FBpp0303635 EnsEMBL-Compara; TreeFam
Haemonchus contortus    HCOI02027400.t1 WormBase-Compara
Heterorhabditis bacteriophora   Hba_15363   WormBase-Compara
Homo sapiens    ENSEMBL:ENSP00000361075 Inparanoid_7; TreeFam
Loa loa EFO26046.2  WormBase-Compara
Meloidogyne hapla   MhA1_Contig1573.frz3.gene15 WormBase-Compara
Mus musculus    ENSEMBL:ENSMUSP00000034296  EnsEMBL-Compara; TreeFam
Onchocerca volvulus WBGene00241206  WormBase-Compara
Panagrellus redivivus   Pan_g2405.t1    WormBase-Compara
Pristionchus pacificus  WBGene00117228  Inparanoid_7; OMA; WormBase-Compara
Trichinella spiralis    EFV56516    WormBase-Compara
=       
WBGene00000002  aat-1   
Ascaris suum    GS_20881    WormBase-Compara
```

Edit:
All I really need from each record is the entry corresponding to "Homo Sapiens". So, ideally, my df in R would be:

```
WBGene00000001 aap-1 Homo sapiens ENSEMBL:ENSP00000361075 Inparanoid_7; TreeFam 
WBGene00000002 aat-1 etc etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `readLines` to read the data into R. Since you gave us the file path in the comments, use `file` to open the connection to the file first, then `readLines`. And it's always good practice to `close` the connection after we've read and stored the data into R.

```
> con <- file("../Input/c_elegans.PRJNA13758.current.best_blastp_hits.txt", 
              open = "r")
> XX <- readLines(con)
> close(con)

> record <- grep("^WBGene", XX, value = TRUE)
> sapien <- grep("Homo sapiens", XX, value = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)
> gsub("\\s+", " ", paste0(record[1], sapien))
## [1] "WBGene00000001 aap-1 Homo sapiens ENSEMBL:ENSP00000361075 Inparanoid_7; TreeFam"
```

The entire `record` vector for your sample data is

```
> record
## [1] "WBGene00000001  aap-1   " "WBGene00000002  aat-1   "
```

So when we find the homo sapien for record 2, it will be pasted to record 2, sapien 3 to record 3, and so on with

```
paste0(record, sapien)
```

**Worth noting** that the OP's data frame was finally created with

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(paste0(record, sapien), split = "\\s+"))
```

Comment: You should show how you generated `XX` (`readLines`, `scan`, `read.table`?).

Comment: hmmm...this makes sense, yet I can't get it to work. I seem to be getting empty characters when i use grep. I'm guessing my file wasn't inputted correctly. Is there anything I should bear in mind while using textConnection and readLines?

Comment: x <- textConnection("../Input/c_elegans.PRJNA13758.current.best_blastp_hits.txt")
blasthits <- readLines(x)

Comment: I tried that first; it didn't work :( I get an error message: Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file '../Input/c_elegans.PRJNA13758.current.best_blastp_hits.txt': No such file or directory

Comment: Grr. I *knew* I should have learnt some programming before becoming a biologist!!!!

Comment: Made an edit to include your file.  Take a look at the first two lines above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51840/discussion-between-kvothe-and-richard-scriven)

Answer (score 0):

This might work too, using "scan":

```
dat <- matrix(unlist(scan(file     = "data",
                      what         = list(""),
                      sep          = "\n",
                      skip         = 8, # file header
                      multi.line   = FALSE)),
          ncol  = 25, # one record span 25 lines
          byrow = TRUE)
paste(dat[,2], dat[,18])
```

Each full line is treated as a field. Each row of dat is a record, where each column is a line. (if needed, it can be split by each '\t').

Finally I combine columns 2 and 18, the ones of interest.

Comment: hmmm..the only problem i see with this is the fact that for every entry, Homo sapiens is not necessarily column 18 - each record in my input has a different length and correspondingly doing it this way will throw out a different number of columns for each record.